# Hyperbolic and Conformal Geometries applied to Relativity Physics - Are there other geometries?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, special-relativity

If we analyse the light spheres in two inertial frames $K_1$ and $K_2$ we have

$$x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2-c_1^2t_1^2=0$$

$$x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2-c_2^2t_2^2=0$$

(making no assumptions as the constancy of $c$ at this stage)

To equate these two equations as Lorentz did we insert an unknown factor $k$, thus

$$x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2-c_2^2t_2^2=k\left(x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2-c_1^2t_1^2\right)$$

Conventionally $k$ has always taken to be equal to one, to give the hyperbolic geometry of special relativity, but it could conceivably take other dimensionless values.

For example if we assume $k=\left(1-v^2/c^2\right)$ then this can form the basis of a theory of relativity based on conformal geometry instead of hyperbolic geometry, with

$$x_2=x_1\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}=\left(x_{12}-v_1t_1\right)\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}$$

$$y_2=y_1\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}$$

$$z_2=z_1\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}$$

$$z_2=z_1\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}$$

$$t_2=\frac{t_1}{\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}}$$

with the velocities varying between frames as well

$$v_2=v_1\left(1-v^2/c^2\right)$$

$$c_2=c_1\left(1-v^2/c^2\right)$$

The inverse relations being

$$x_{12}=\frac{x_2+v_2t_2}{\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}}$$

$$y_1=\frac{y_2}{\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}}$$

$$z_1=\frac{z_2}{\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}}$$

$$t_1=t_2\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}$$

$$v_1=\frac{v_2}{\left(1-v^2/c^2\right)}$$

$$c_1=\frac{c_2}{\left(1-v^2/c^2\right)}$$

This is a conformal approach and "relativistic" Dimensional Analysis can be applied. That is dimensional homogeneity applies in respect of the applied relativistic factor to dimensions of [Length], [Length$^2$] etc.

This sort of theory implies absolute motion in physical space exists, even though it is unobservable on making a measurement (measurements are always determined by ratio of two **physical quantities** of the same type and this results in the automatic **cancelation of any relativistic factor**).

**Ignoring the physical viability of this alternative geometry, can $k$ take any other values which result in other consistent geometries other than *hyperbolic* or *conformal*?**

Comment: The terminology I have used in respect the geometry of special relativity could be improved; it is a type of projective geometry which involves hyperbolic trigonometry - which is not the same thing as a non-Euclidean hyperbolic geometry. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714906/why-is-spacetime-in-special-relativity-hyperbolic

Comment: where did k come from? you're arbitrarily changing the metric.